# Different ways of declaring a function

Tags: list, function, ocaml

When declaring a function, I've 3 different ways:

```ml
let f x = ...

let f = (fun x -> ...)

let f = function
    | ...  -> (pattern matching)
```

It's this last one that I don't fully understand how it works.

I was doing a function that, considering a list (we'll assume it has integers in it but could be anything), reverses it, pretty basic, but with a complexity of O(n). After struggling for an hour at least I check the answer, and it is written like this:

```ml
let reverse lst =
    let rec aux acc = function
          | [] -> acc
          | hd :: tl -> aux (hd :: acc) tl
    in
    aux [] lst
```

I thought that using the key word function was just another way of doing patter matching, but when I do this:

```ml
let reverse lst =
    let rec aux acc = 
        match aux with 
          | [] -> acc
          | hd :: tl -> aux (hd :: acc) tl
    in
    aux [] lst
```

It doesn't work, and idk why. On top of that, why can we add `tl` at the end of the first function? Isn't `aux` a single argument function?

Comment: Using the keyword `function` creates a one-argument function. If you write `let rec aux acc = function ...`, then `aux` becomes a two-argument function: the first argument is `acc`, and the second argument is introduced by `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Ocaml uses currying, which means that a two-argument function is the same thing that a function whose return value is a function.

To define a two-argument function, you can combine all the ways you know of creating one-argument functions:

```ml
let f x y = x + y

let f x = (fun y -> x + y)

let f x = function
    | y -> x + y

let f = (fun x -> (fun y -> x + y))

let f = function
    | x -> function
        | y -> x + y

let f x = (let g y = x + y in g)

etc, etc.
```

All these definitions for `f` lead to the same result:

```ml
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>

# f 3 4;;
- : int = 7
```

Note that the signature of `f` is:

```ml
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

If we added parentheses to better understand this signature, it would be this:

```ml
val f : int -> (int -> int) = <fun>
```

Meaning that `f` is a one-argument function whose return value is a one-argument function whose return value is an int.

Indeed, if we partially apply `f`:

```ml
# f 3;;
- : int -> int = <fun>

# let add_three = f 3;;
val add_three : int -> int = <fun>

# add_three 4;;
- : int = 7
```

The code you give at the end of your question is wrong. It's most likely intended to be this:

```ml
let reverse lst =
    let rec aux acc l = 
        match l with 
          | [] -> acc
          | hd :: tl -> aux (hd :: acc) tl
    in
    aux [] lst;;

val reverse : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

# reverse [1;2;3;4;5];;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1]
```

Comment: So basically, when using "function", the second variable is implicit, which means whenever i call my function again in the code i can add another variable ? Is the type of that second variable 'a by default ?

Comment: @EZVac When you use `function`, it adds one variable. If you write `let f = (function _ -> 3)` then you have one variable. If you write `let f = (function _ -> (function _ -> 3))` then you have two variables. If you write `let f x y = 3` then you have two variables. If you write `let f x = (function _ -> 3)` then you have two variables. There is nothing implicit.

Comment: The type is determined, as always, by what you do with it. If you write `let f x = function _ -> x` then the type of both the first variable will be `'a` and the second variable `'b`. But if you write `let f x = function y -> x + y` then the type of both variables will be `int` because of the `+`. And if you write `let f = function | h :: t -> 3` then the type of the variable will be `'a list` since only lists can be pattern-matched to `h :: t`. And if you write `let rec f = function | [] -> 0 | h :: t -> h + f t` then the type of the variable will be `int list`.